# How do I pass a variable two levels in a nested Rspec shared example?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec3

Basically, I have a bunch of shared examples. I thought this would work, but I'm getting `stack level too deep` on the variable that's being passed.

```
shared_examples 'Foo' do
  # top level shared example passes values
  # to a lower-level shared example.
  it_behaves_like 'Bar' do
    let(:variable) { variable }
  end

  it_behaves_like 'Baz'
end

shared_examples 'Bar' do
  it { expect(variable).to veq('value')
end
```

the spec:

```
describe SomeClass do
  it_behaves_like 'Foo' do
    let(:variable) { 'value' }
  end
end
```

I thought shared examples kept their own context, why is this causing an issue?

Comment: I think you have a recursion in your code: `let(:variable) { variable }` calls itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have recursion in your code:

```
let(:variable) { variable }
```

will call itself over and over again

---

Specs will pass down their variables automatically, so this will work:

```
shared_examples 'Foo' do
  it_behaves_like 'Bar'
  it_behaves_like 'Baz'
end

shared_examples 'Bar' do
  it { expect(variable).to eq('value') }
end
```

and

```
describe SomeClass do
  let(:variable) { 'value' }
  it_behaves_like 'Foo'
end
```